# excel - inserting a value based on a range of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to link a batch code to a specific unit number.  The batch codes are the same for a range of unit numbers.  The first table below shows the unit numbers; the “?” marks are where I need to enter the batch code that matches that unit.  The second table shows the range of numbers per batch code.  Any thoughts on how to do this great appreciated!

```
Unit number     Batch
   1367           ?
   1245           ?
   1392           ?
   2051           ?
   3040           ?
```

```
bottom number range   top number range   Batch
        1245                1367         ABCD
        1389                1467         EFGH
        1500                2000         IJKL
        2050                3000         MNOP
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a table with what the batchcodes mean. This can be in a different sheet, as long as it is in the same workbook (otherwise it might break, or the lookup doesn't work properly.)

In the actual sheet, in A you have the batch numbers. In B you would add a =VLOOKUP(A1,!sheet2.A:B,2,FALSE)

See also: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx